# Changing color of each row with jQuery dialog .append

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am building an application that would allow adding tasks to the list and changing the colour of them according to what selections were made.

I am using it to build a list of items, now how could I achieve something like this http://s4.postimg.org/npplicbnh/2222.png

Here is my .append code that @Narawa Games helped me with. However at the moment whenever a new item is added it changes the color of every other item that was added before it into the same color. I want to be able to have different items in different colors.

```
if ( valid ) {
    $( "#tasks2 tbody" ).append("\<div class='taskList'><ul class='taskScreen2'><tr>" 
    + "<td><h1>"  
    + type.val() 
    + "</h1></td>"
    +"<td class='title'><h3>"
    +  title.val() 
    + " </td>"  
    +"<td>"
    + wordcount.val() 
    + "</h3></td>"  
    +"<td><p>"
    +  description.val() 
    + "</p></td>"  
    + "<td>"
    + deadline.val() 
    + "</td>"
    + "</tr></ul></div>"
    +"<script>var typeSUP=$('#type').val();var taskS=$('.taskList');if(typeSUP=='Dissertation'){taskS.css('border-color', 'red');}else if (typeSUP=='Report'){taskS.css('border-color', 'blue');}\
");
```

Here's a jsfiddle example - https://jsfiddle.net/ynwLykpk/

All help is welcome. Cheers

Comment: You need to define the rules for " different items in different colors".

Comment: Please turn your code into a working snippet or a fiddle.

Comment: Its a little difficult to work on this question. I suggest, as @Banana said, you make a complete working example on jsfiddle. That way we can reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to style the table row that was just added, and leave others untouched, then try :

```
if ( valid ) {
    var $task = $("<tr class='taskList'>" 
        + "<td><h1>" + type.val() + "</h1></td>"
        + "<td class='title'><h3>" +  title.val() + "</h3></td>"  
        + "<td>" + wordcount.val() + "</td>"  
        + "<td><p>" + description.val() + "</p></td>"  
        + "<td>" + deadline.val() + "</td>"
        + "</tr>"
    ).appendTo("#tasks2 tbody");
    switch($('#type').val()) {
        case 'Dissertation':
            $task.css('border-color', 'red');
        break;
        case 'Report':
            $task.css('border-color', 'blue');
        break;
        default:
            $task.css('border-color', 'green');
    }
}
```

Tidied up because appending `<div><ul><tr>...</tr></ul></div>` to a `tbody` element is a nonsense.

**Edit in response to @Tushars comments**

Alternatively, write CSS directives for default and each task type :

```
.taskList {
    border-color: green;
}
.taskList.Dissertation {
    border-color: red;
}
.taskList.Report {
    border-color: blue;
}
```

Then style rows by applying the appropriate class to the row :

```
if ( valid ) {
    var type = type.val();
    $("<tr class='taskList'>" 
        + "<td><h1>" + type.val() + "</h1></td>"
        + "<td class='title'><h3>" +  title.val() + "</h3></td>"  
        + "<td>" + wordcount.val() + "</td>"  
        + "<td><p>" + description.val() + "</p></td>"  
        + "<td>" + deadline.val() + "</td>"
        + "</tr>"
    ).addClass(type).appendTo("#tasks2 tbody");
}
```

Comment: You missed the `break` of Report

Comment: It would be better if you create classes of the cases and add them directly. Will save `switch`

Comment: Adding a class would be an alternative to `.css(...)`. You would still need to branch with `switch` or `if(...) {...} else if(...) {...} else {...}`.

Comment: No. Create class with name `Report` having border-color blue. And same for others. And add the `#type` value as class.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Thank you so much for your suggestion, was able to get it working. One more question, is it possible to create a function somehow that would allow to edit the items directly from the list?

Comment: @EgidijusPoškus, I have added something to reflect Tushar's comments,

Comment: @EgidijusPoškus, yes it is possible to give each row an "Edit" button with appropriate functionality, but that would need to be another Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Fair enough, thank you so much for this though, some really good stuff and a good learning experience for me.